# Yii Model ManyToMany Relation with another 2 models

Tags: php, jquery, yii, model, many-to-many

first of all I apologize for any mistake in writing

Well, let me explain

I have 3 models, the Music Model, the MusicLink Model and the MusicGenre Model.
In the MusicController, i have the action "Create".

Then, on the form, I have the fields of Music Model, and 2 other fields.
Select2 a widget that lets you select multiple Genres, and another field for the links (urls of the music file) that can be dynamically cloned by jQuery plugin "RelCopy" (up to a maximum of to 6 fields)

An music can have multiple genres, as well as several links

My problem is how to save all these fields, correctly? I hope I'm being clear enough.

Here is the code I have so far:

**MusicController.php**

```
/**
* Creates a new model.
* If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
*/
public function actionCreate()
{
$music = new Music;
$genre = new MusicGenre;
$link = new MusicLink;

// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($music);

if(isset($_POST['Music']) && isset($_POST['MusicGenre']))
{
    CActiveForm::validate($genre);
    CActiveForm::validate($link);
    $music->attributes=$_POST['Music'];
    if($music->save()){
        foreach(explode(',',$_POST['MusicGenre']['genre_id']) as $gen)
        {
            $genre=new MusicGenre;
            $genre->genre_id = $gen;
            $genre->music_id = $music->id;
            if($genre->validate())
                $valid[]=true;
            else
                $valid[]=false;
        }

        foreach($_POST['Music']['links'] as $lnk)
        {
            $link=new MusicLink;
            $link->link = $lnk;
            $link->music_id = $music->id;
            $link->host = MusicLink::model()->getHoster($lnk);
            if($link->validate())
                $valid[]=true;
            else
                $valid[]=false;
        }
        if(!in_array(false,$valid)){
            $genre->save();
            $link->save();
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$music->id));
        }
    }
}

$this->render('create',array(
'music'=>$music,
'genre'=>$genre,
'link'=>$link,
));
}

/**
* Updates a particular model.
* If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
* @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
*/
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
$music = $this->loadModel($id);
$genre = MusicGenre::model()->findByAttributes(array('music_id'=>$id));//new MusicGenre;
$link = MusicLink::model()->findAll('music_id=:mID',array(':mID'=>$id));;
// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($music);

if(isset($_POST['Music']) && isset($_POST['MusicGenre']))
{
    $music->attributes=$_POST['Music'];
    if($music->save()){
        foreach(explode(',',$_POST['MusicGenre']['genre_id']) as $gen)
        {
            //$genre = MusicGenre::model()->findByAttributes(array('music_id'=>$music->id));
            $genre->genre_id = Genre::model()->nameToId($gen);
            $genre->music_id = $music->id;
            $valid[]=$genre->save();
        }
        foreach($_POST['Music']['links'] as $lid => $lnk)
        {
            $link = MusicLink::model()->find('music_id=:mID AND id=:lID',array(':mID'=>$music->id,':lID'=>$lid));
            if($link == null){
                $link=new MusicLink;
                $link->link = $lnk;
                $link->music_id = $music->id;
                $link->host = MusicLink::model()->getHoster($lnk);
                $valid[]=$link->save();
            }else if($link->link != $lnk){
                $link->link = $lnk;
                $link->music_id = $music->id;
                $link->host = MusicLink::model()->getHoster($lnk);
                $valid[]=$link->save();
            }
        }
        if(!in_array(false,$valid))
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$music->id));
    }
}
$this->render('update',array(
'music'=>$music,
'genre'=>$genre,
'link'=>$link,
));
}
```

**\music_form.php**

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm',array(
    'id'=>'music-form',
    'type' => 'horizontal',
    'customCssErrors' => 'inline',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>
<fieldset>

<legend>
<?php echo $music->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('b2r','Create Music') : Yii::t('b2r','Update Music') ;?>
</legend>
<p class="help-block well well-small"><?php echo Yii::t('b2r','Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.'); ?>
</p>
<?php
$models = array($music,$genre);
if (is_array($link))
    foreach ($link as $lnk)
        $models[] = $lnk;
else
    $models[] = $link;

//die(var_dump($models));
?>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($models); ?>

<div class="span6 first">
    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($music,'artist',array('class'=>'span12','maxlength'=>255)); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($music,'title',array('class'=>'span12','maxlength'=>255)); ?>

    <?php echo $form->textAreaRow($music,'desc',array('rows'=>3, 'cols'=>60, 'class'=>'span12')); ?>

    <?php echo $form->select2Row($genre, 'genre_id', array(
                        'asDropDownList' => false,
                        'val' => MusicGenre::model()->getMusicGenresNames($music->id),
                        'options' => array(
                            'data' => Genre::model()->getGenres(),
                            'placeholder' => 'Escreva um ou mais categorias, separadas por virgulas',
                            'containerCssClass' => 'span12',
                            'tokenSeparators' => array(','),
                            'multiple'=>true,
                            'width'=>'none',
                            'initSelection' => 'js:function (element, callback) {
                                  var val = [];
                                  $(element.val().split(",")).each(function () {
                                      val.push({id: this, text: this});
                                  });

                                  callback(val);
                            }'
                        )
                      )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->maskedTextFieldRow($music,'length',array('mask'=>'99:99?:99','htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'span12','maxlength'=>8)),array('hint'=>Yii::t('b2r','No formato {f1} ou {f2}',array('{f1}'=>'<i class="label label-info">MM:SS</i>','{f2}'=>'<i class="label label-info">HH:MM:SS</i>')))); ?>

    <?php echo $form->maskedTextFieldRow($music,'size',array('mask'=>'?~~~.~~','charMap'=>array('~'=>'^[0-9]+(\.)?[0-9]{0,2}$'),'placeholder'=>'0','htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'span12','maxlength'=>8)),array('hint'=>Yii::t('b2r','No formato {f1} ou {f2}',array('{f1}'=>'<i class="label label-info">xx.xx</i>','{f2}'=>'<i class="label label-info">xxx.xx</i>')))); ?>

</div>
<div class="span6">
    <div class="controls">
        <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span5">
                <a class="thumbnail">
                <?php echo CHtml::image('/images/capa.gif',Yii::t('b2r','Previsualização da Imagem'),
                        array('id'=>'previewHolder','width'=>'170px','height'=>'170px')); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($music,'image',array('class'=>'span8','maxlength'=>255),array('controlCss'=>'skipcopy','append'=>'<a href="#" id="findcover" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'.Yii::t('b2r','Procurar capa no Google').'"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-right"></i></a>')); ?>

    <?php
    if ($music->isNewRecord){
        echo $form->textFieldRow($link,'link',
            array('name'=>'MusicLink[links][0]','value'=>'','maxlength'=>255, 'class'=>'span8'),
            array('controlCss'=>'copy clonable','append'=>'<a id="copylink" href="#" rel=".copy"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a> ')
        );
    }else{
        $last = count($link)-1;
        foreach ($link as $k => $v)
            die(var_dump($link));
            $id = (is_null($v)) ? $k : $v->id;
            if($k == $last)
                echo $form->textFieldRow($v,'link',
                    array('name'=>'MusicLink[links]['.$id.']','maxlength'=>255, 'class'=>'span8'),
                    array('controlCss'=>'copy clonable','label'=>'<span class="required">*</span>','append'=>'<a id="copylink" href="#" rel=".copy"><i class="icon-plus"></i></a> ')
                );
            else
                echo $form->textFieldRow($v,'link',
                    array('name'=>'MusicLink[links]['.$id.']','maxlength'=>255, 'class'=>'span8'),
                    array('controlCss'=>'clonable')
                );
    }
    ?>

<?php
$this->widget('ext.jqrelcopy.JQRelcopy',array(

 //the id of the 'Copy' link in the view, see below.
 'id' => 'copylink',

  //add a icon image tag instead of the text
  //leave empty to disable removing
 'removeText' => '<i class="icon-remove"></i>',

 //htmlOptions of the remove link
 'removeHtmlOptions' => array('style'=>'margin-left:2px;padding:3px 10px;','class'=>'btn btn-small btn-danger'),

 //options of the plugin, see http://www.andresvidal.com/labs/relcopy.html
 'options' => array(

       //A class to attach to each copy
      'copyClass'=>'newcopy',

      // The number of allowed copies. Default: 0 is unlimited
      'limit'=>6,

      //Option to clear each copies text input fields or textarea
      'clearInputs'=>true,

      //A jQuery selector used to exclude an element and its children
      'excludeSelector'=>'.skipcopy',

      //Additional HTML to attach at the end of each copy.
      //'append'=>CHtml::tag('span',array('class'=>'hint'),'You can remove this line'),
       //'jsAfterNewId' => "if(typeof $(this > input).attr('name') !== 'undefined'){ $(this > input).attr('name', $(this > input).attr('name').replace('new', 'new_'+counter));}",

   )
));
?>
</div>
<?php $collapse = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbCollapse',array('htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'span12 first'))); ?>
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
            Avançado
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <?php echo $form->textFieldRow($music,'bitrate',array('class'=>'span9')); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</fieldset>

<div class="form-actions">
    <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
            'buttonType'=>'submit',
            'type'=>'primary',
            'label'=>$music->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('b2r','Create') : Yii::t('b2r','Save'),
        )); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('script', "
   $('#Music_image').change(function() {
       $('#previewHolder').attr('src',$(this).val());
   });
   $('#findcover').click(function() {
       var q = $('#Music_artist').val();
       q += ' - '+$('#Music_title').val();
       q += ' cover';
       window.open('https://www.google.pt/search?q='+escape(q)+'&tbm=isch', '_blank');
   });
"
, CClientScript::POS_READY);?>
```

---

**EDIT**

With this code, I can save everything correctly, but for example, if I do not select a Genre, or not enter a link to the file, only saves the music.
But for example, if has missing a required field of Music Model, as well as MusicGenres or MusicLink model, is validated all three Models.
If the errors only belong to MusicGenre or MusicLink model, the music is saved, but not these 2 Models

---

I'm using Yii version 1.1.14, with YiiBoostrap and YiiBoilerplate

Here are the links to the plugins:

http://www.andresvidal.com/labs/relcopy.html

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what's your problem. Your code seems to work. Maybe you shoud enclose all saves into a transaction.

Comment: it works, yes, but if i dont select any genre or write a music link, it saves, and dont show the errors in the form

Answer (score 1):

You may use [esaverelatedbehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/esaverelatedbehavior/) component developed by sluderitz for saving related models, you can download it here

After installing above extension you can do like this

```
$music->attributes=$_POST['Music'];

if (isset($_POST['MusicGenre']))
{
    $music->musicgenre= $_POST['MusicGenre'];
}
if ($music->saveWithRelated('musicgenre'))
    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->id));
```

Note: We are able to do `$music->musicgenre` because `musicgenre` is a relation name.

A detailed solution for [saving multiple related models](http://scriptbaker.com/how-to-save-multiple-related-models-in-yii-complete-solution/) using above extension is available in my blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I know wat you want.

In the create method, when you test if the array of generes or links are valid you can generate an error message and redirect to the update action and ask to the user to insert the generes or links data.

In the actionCreate:

```
if($music->save()){

     ......

    if(!in_array(false,$valid)){
        $genre->save();
        $link->save();
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$music->id));
    } 
    else {
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error',"Some cool warning message");
        $this->redirect(array('update','id'=>$music->id)));
    }
}
     ......
```

In the ActionUpdate do the same:

```
........
if(!in_array(false,$valid))
        $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$music->id));
else
        Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error',"Some cool warning message");
```

Now, in the update view file (not in the _form) you must show the error message:

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('error')):?>
<div class="flash-error">
    <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

There's a default CSS defined fot the "flash-error" DIV. See [enter link description here](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/).

I hope it helps you.

ANOTHER POSSIBLE SOLUTION can be definig an array for the generes and links into music model.
then, assign the form's values in these variables befor calling $music->saave.
In the music model you must write validaors rules for the arrays and in  <strike>[beforeSave()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#beforeSave-detail)</strike> [afterSave()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterSave-detail) method write the code to insert the genere and links rows.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
I know I'm not being explicit, even in Portuguese is difficult to explain, in English I do not see how to do, I'll edit the question in order to be able to explain what I want

Comment: Don't worry about your english. I'm from Spain and my english is even worst than yours. Do you test my suggestions?. I think that it resolve your problem.

Comment: I have not tested because it is not exactly what I want.
I plan to show that the errors normally through the `$form-> ErrorSummary();`

Comment: But the result is the same. When the user adds a new music element without genere, redirects to the update view showing the music data just inserted with the error message asking the user for put the missed data. I think that will work, but you can check the generes and links into the Music Model.

Comment: hello buddy, I've got solve, due to its tip of another possible solution.
Just missing a detail. how I can get the id of MUSIC MODEL on the beforeSave?
----------
could you edit the post so I can accept the answer?

Comment: You are right. In breforeSave method you don't have access to the primary key because it's nor created yet. So you will need overwrite the afterSave method. I will edit my wnswer.

Comment: but it as a problem, if it as any error saving the related models in "afterSave" of Music model, how i do some kind of rollback? :/

Comment: If an error is launched inserting the genere or links tables, you can delete the values inserted in music table, or maybe, if you database allows transactions, the best solution would be to do all operations into a transaction and roll back if there's any error.

Comment: I had also thought of that, but maybe it's a bit inefficient the first option, no?

and how to use "separate" transactions? is possible start in actionCreate and finish the transaction on afterSave?

Comment: I don't think thas was ineficient unless you have a heavy access to your database. The transactions are at database level, so you can start a transaction in the action method and commit or rollback in aftersave.

Comment: nice, i will try the transactions in that way and see if it works :D thanks